# Access composite data in Postgres via Apache Drill

Tags: java, apache, postgresql, apache-drill

I am fairly new to Apache Drill. I need to query my PostgreSQL database
using Apache Drill.
I went through the [documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/) and could
configure a storage plugin for my Postgres database.

```
{

  "type": "jdbc",

  "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",

  "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb",

  "username": <username>,

  "password": <password>,

  "enabled": true

}
```

I can successfully query tables with primary datatypes but unable to query
the ones that have composite datatype.
I have tried querying it using various ways, [example](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/08/an-introduction-to-apache-drill/).

This is the exception i get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at
org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.RelStructuredTypeFlattener.restructureFields(RelStructuredTypeFlattener.java:201)
~[calcite-core-1.4.0-drill-r21.jar:1.4.0-drill-r21]
at
org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.RelStructuredTypeFlattener.restructure(RelStructuredTypeFlattener.java:225)
~[calcite-core-1.4.0-drill-r21.jar:1.4.0-drill-r21]
at
org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.RelStructuredTypeFlattener.restructureFields(RelStructuredTypeFlattener.java:205)
~[calcite-core-1.4.0-drill-r21.jar:1.4.0-drill-r21]
at
org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.RelStructuredTypeFlattener.rewrite(RelStructuredTypeFlattener.java:184)
~[calcite-core-1.4.0-drill-r21.jar:1.4.0-drill-r21]
at
org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.flattenTypes(SqlToRelConverter.java:435)
~[calcite-core-1.4.0-drill-r21.jar:1.4.0-drill-r21]
at
org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter.toRel(SqlConverter.java:270)
~[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
at
org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.convertToRel(DefaultSqlHandler.java:638)
~[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
at
org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.validateAndConvert(DefaultSqlHandler.java:196)
~[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
at
org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.getPlan(DefaultSqlHandler.java:165)
~[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
at
org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getQueryPlan(DrillSqlWorker.java:131)
~[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
at
org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan(DrillSqlWorker.java:79)
~[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
at org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL(Foreman.java:1050)
[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
at org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run(Foreman.java:280)
[drill-java-exec-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
```

Is querying composite datatype in drill not feasible at all?
Please let me know if am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache Drill v1.11 documentation for data types: https://drill.apache.org/docs/supported-data-types/

> In this release of Drill, you cannot reference a composite type by name in a query, but Drill supports array values coming from data sources.

**EDIT**

I suggest trying the ways provided by the Apache Drill community in the documentation. This is a bit from the section *Composite Types*:

> For example, you can use the index syntax to query data and get the value of an array element:
>
> `a[1]`
>
> You can refer to the value for a key in a map using dot notation:
>
> `t.m.k`
>
> The section “[Query Complex Data](https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-complex-data-introduction)” shows how to use composite types to access nested arrays. "[Handling Different Data Types](https://drill.apache.org/docs/handling-different-data-types/#handling-json-and-parquet-data)" includes examples of JSON maps and arrays. Drill provides functions for handling array and map types:
>
> - "[KVGEN](https://drill.apache.org/docs/kvgen/)"
> - "[FLATTEN](https://drill.apache.org/docs/flatten/)"

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to work around this issue?

Comment: I have tried querying the data that way, it throws  AssertionError: STRUCTURED. The query: select tb.account_user.description as record from doc.complex as tb; where account_user is my object, description is the field within it. doc: schema, complex: table name.